# Does a single theme license work on multisite?

Tags: multisite, themes, premium

I am trying to create a multisite network and I want all of the sites in that network to look similar. So, I am planning to install a single premium theme in the whole network. My question is, will the same license work for all the sites in the network or will I have to purchase individual license?

Comment: This question is best asked of the person selling the license. This question cannot be answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends upon the seller of the theme. Contact them if their license is not clear about this. I ran across a couple of sellers of plugins (not sure about their themes) that have a special license specifically for multisite networks, while others say that if the sites are related in use (say one business' main site and the same business' blog site), you only need one license but if the sites are for different businesses, you need a license for each site. Whether the sites have their own domain names rather than just subdomain names can make a difference too.